# How do I update a users input in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm making a program for a car dealership as my final project for my class. At this time I'd say I'm about 75% done, but I am having trouble figuring out how to update the users input in an array list. So each array list slot contains the year, make, model, color, and mileage of a car. I can add a new car, I can remove a car, and I can quit my program. I have tried many things, I've read many papers, blogs, forums, and my book for class, but its always updating with the programmers input.

```
package carDealer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VehicleInformation {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<VehicleInventory> car = new ArrayList<VehicleInventory>();
    String userInput = "-";

    while (!userInput.equals("q")) {
        System.out.println("Commands: 'a' to add, 'd' to delete, 'e' to edit, 'q' to quit");
        userInput = scnr.next();

        if (userInput.equals("a")) {
            System.out.println("Year: ");
            int year = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Make: ");
            String make = scnr.next();
            System.out.println("Model: ");
            String model = scnr.next();
            System.out.println("Color: ");
            String color = scnr.next();
            System.out.println("Mileage: ");
            int mileage = scnr.nextInt();

            VehicleInventory userCar = new VehicleInventory();      
            userCar.setMake(make);
            userCar.setModel(model);
            userCar.setYear(year);
            userCar.setColor(color);
            userCar.setMileage(mileage);
            userCar.print();

            addCar(car, userCar);
        }

        if (userInput.equals("d")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < car.size(); ++i) {
                System.out.print((i + 1) + " ");
                car.get(i).print();
            }

            System.out.println("List number: ");
            int userNum = scnr.nextInt();
            car.remove(userNum - 1);
            System.out.println("count: " + car.size());
        }

        if (userInput.equals("e")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < car.size(); ++i) {
                System.out.print((i + 1) + " ");
                car.get(i).print();

            }

            System.out.println("List number: ");
            int userNum = scnr.nextInt();
            car.get(userNum - 1);
```

Comment: Where's your addCar() method?

Comment: The last 25% always take 75% of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do a loop to look up for the car model the user wants to update (it can be any other attribute), and once found update it's value with the desired one:

```
String vehicleToLookUp = "golf"; // This will be received by user input
String vehicleNewName = "golf gti"; // This will be received by user input
for( int i = 0; i < car.size(); i++){
    if(vehicleToLookUp.getModel().equals(car.get(i)){
        car.get(i).setSomeAttribute(...); // Set the desired attribute here
    }
}
```

Or if you want to substitute the whole object...

```
String vehicleToLookUp = "golf"; // This will be received by user input
VehicleInventory newVehicle = new VehicleInventory(); // You will set the attributes by user input
for( int i = 0; i < car.size(); i++){
    if(vehicleToLookUp.getModel().equals(car.get(i)){
        car.set(i, newVehicle ); // Create your object and pass it here
    }
}
```

Also, instead of all those `if`, you could use `if/else if` or even a `switch/case` for better performance/readability (think that even if your logic is true for first `if`, it will check for all the other `if` you created, wasting time and processing power.

Comment: if (userInput.equals("year")) {
     System.out.println("What year is it?");
     userNum = scnr.nextInt();
     carToModify.setYear(userNum);
This is what i ended up using to modify each individual part, thank you for the speedy response though!